# USB Debugging turned off at reboot

Tags: usb-debugging

I have a rooted Android tablet running 4.0.1.

Ever since I got it, the USB Debugging option doesn't stick after a reboot.

This can be quite problematic, so how do I stop this, and make USB Debugging stick?

I am still running the stock ROM, which has been compiled in userdebug mode.

Comment: Is this the same tablet that your brother locked you out of? What has userdebug mode got to do with stock rom?

Comment: @t0mm13b Yup. Just thought I'd add that it isn't compiled in production mode.

Comment: Hang on, in your previous post asking for help in how to get the tablet back despite numerous attempts to get  it unlocked, you stated that it was un-rooted, so I'll assume you wiped and installed stock rom? If so, what is your point in mentioning about whether its compiled in userdebug mode? Did you compile it yourself...?

Comment: It was rooted in my previous question... I have never installed a new a ROM.